# Is it possible to apply scanline shader without using FrameBuffer?

Tags: libgdx, glsl

I'm looking for a minimal scanline shader to use with libGDX, preferably with the option to alter the intensity of the effect.

There's a libGDX example here (missing the vert and frag files):

[Shaders in libgdx have no effect [Desktop]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074698/shaders-in-libgdx-have-no-effect-desktop)

However, this requires the use of a FrameBuffer. Is there a more elegant solution, where I can just drop the vert and frag files into my shaders folder, then setup in my code like this:

```
private String vertexShader;
private String fragmentShader;
private ShaderProgram shaderProgram;

@Override
public void create()
{
  vertexShader = Gdx.files.internal("shaders/vertex.glsl").readString();
  fragmentShader = Gdx.files.internal("shaders/fragment.glsl").readString();
  shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
  spriteBatch.setShader(shaderProgram);
}
```

My game is targeted at low-end Android phones. I currently get a reasonably stable 60fps, and would like to keep this performance.

*edit 1:*
Following Tenfour04's snippet, my vertex file currently looks like this:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
uniform float u_screenHeight;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main()
{
  v_color = a_color;
  v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
  gl_Position =  u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

*edit 2:*
New, possibly simpler method, but rendering loses transparency:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
  precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

uniform sampler2D u_sampler2D;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main(void)
{
  vec2 p = vec2(floor(gl_FragCoord.x), floor(gl_FragCoord.y));
  if (mod(p.y, 2.0)==0.0)
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(u_sampler2D,v_texCoords).xyz ,1.0);
  else
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0 ,1.0);
}
```

Comment: Depends on how realistic you want the scan lines to look. If they don't have to look blurred like real ones, you can do this.

Comment: They don't have to look blurred, but it would be nice if I could change the transparency level of the lines so the effect isn't too harsh. Do you have an example I could use?

Comment: `gl_FragColor = vec4(max(step(u_ScanlineWidth/*1.*/,mod(gl_FragCoord.y,u_ScanlineSpacing/*2.*/)),1.-u_ScanlineIntensity/*.5*/)*texture2D(u_sampler2D,v_texCoords).rgb,1.);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shader I think will work. I didn't test it, so you might have to debug it. You can customize the line count and intensity constants to get the look you want. This is very simply based off a sine curve, and it only causes darkening. There are more elaborate effects you could do by lightening and darkening the color using the sine wave. You could also truncate the sine function with step functions to possibly increase its realism.

```
//Vertex shader (same as SpriteBatch's default)
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying vec4 v_color;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main()
{
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    v_color = a_color;
    v_color.a = v_color.a * (255.0/254.0);
    gl_Position =  u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

```
//Fragment shader
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

const float LINE_COUNT = 90.0;
const float FREQ = LINE_COUNT * 2.0 * 3.14159;
const float INTENSITY = 0.4;

varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying vec3 v_color;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform float u_screenHeight;

void main()
{
    vec4 texture = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
    float screenV = gl_FragCoord.y / u_screenHeight;
    float scanLine = 1.0 - INTENSITY * (sin(FREQ * screenV) * 0.5 + 0.5);

    //Possibly cheaper methods, in increasing realism / performance hit
    //float scanLine = 1.0 - INTENSITY * mod(screenV * LINE_COUNT, 1.0);
    //float scanLine = 1.0 - INTENSITY * step(0.5, mod(screenV * LINE_COUNT, 1.0));
    //float scanLine = 1.0 - INTENSITY * abs(mod(screenV * LINE_COUNT, 1.0) - 0.5);

    gl_FragColor = v_color * vec4(texture.rgb * scanLine, texture.a);
}
```

It uses screen height as a parameter, so you have to set the screen height when the screen is resized:

```java
public void resize (int width, int height){
    //...

    shader.begin();
    shader.setUniformf("u_screenHeight", height);
    shader.end();
}
```

If you use one of the `mod()` scan line calculations above that I commented out instead of the `sin()` based one, you can further optimize by changing this to:

```
shader.setUniformf("u_screenHeight", LINE_COUNT / (float)height);
```

and changing the shader's `screenV` line's `/` to a `*`, and then removing `* LINE_COUNT` from the scanLine calculation. This would save an operation, and also I think * is slightly faster than /. (If you do this, you might consider renaming the u_screenHeight variable to something that makes sense.)

Comment: Thanks for posting that. Could I see your vertex file? I've added what I'm using to my original post, but I can't get it to work. I get the error: "no uniform with name 'u_screenHeight' in shader"

Comment: The error occurs on resize at the line: shaderProgram.setUniformf("u_screenHeight", height);

Comment: That could happen if the shader failed to compile. You can see what the error was with shader.getLog(). The vertex shader you can just copy from the SpriteBatch source code.

Comment: Managed to get it working, and it looks great, however, it kills performance on my mobile (ZTE-BLADE). I realise that this is an ancient device, but without the shader running, I get a pretty decent fps of 55 to 60. I've been looking at a (possibly) simpler and less intensive solution. I've added it to my OP. This works, however, transparency isn't working. I've seen this issue mentioned elsewhere, but couldn't find a solution. Is this something that needs to be changed in my Java code or the shader?

Comment: In your revised shader, you're throwing away texture alpha, so that's why that happens. It also has a couple of likely performance issues. 1.You're flooring fragCoord.x and not using it. Flooring is unnecessary anyway because you can use < instead of ==. 2. Branching on a conditional that doesn't always evaluate the same usually causes a significant slow-down. The step function is already available and optimized on GPUs. I added a couple of alternate `scanLine` approaches that may perform better at the expense of quality.

Comment: If you're not using vertex color, you can take out the `v_color *` from the last line to save that operation. Also, you can remove `1.0 -` from the scanLine calculation, and change the `*` in the last line to a `-`, also saving an operation (but you'll have to reduce INTENSITY to get it to look similar).

Comment: And of course, you can look at optimizing areas other than the shader to make up for the performance hit. Like avoiding overdraw, turning off blending while drawing the background, using polygon sprites if your sprites have a lot of empty space, etc.

Comment: I made the optimisations you recommended, and performance is up, but still sub-40fps. I'd already optimised this game to within an inch of its life, and had already done the things you recommended, although not sure what you mean by overdraw. My phone is 6 years old though, so I'm guessing that anything released even 6 months after this model is not going to see the same issues. I think I will add a scanlines option that is off by default so people on older devices like mine can still play it at 60fps. Eitherway, many thanks for all your help.

Comment: Overdraw is drawing over the same pixel multiple times because of sprites overlapping each other a lot. You can sometimes reduce it by using polygon sprites to avoid drawing invisible pixels. If you are using "retro" low-res graphics, and you have a lot of overdraw, it might actually be faster to render your whole game to a small frame buffer and then render the frame buffer at full scale with a scan line shader.

Comment: Just my opinion, but I don't think someone with a 6 year old device should expect better than 30fps. Most AAA console games run at 30fps anyway (though I admit 60fps is more crucial for side-scrolling games).

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your method and still have transparency.

This is the main() in my fragment shader:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates);
if (mod(floor(gl_FragCoord.y),4.0) == 0.0)
    gl_FragColor.rgb *= 0.5;
```

With this I have transparent textures showing cheap scanlines. Note that I'm using 4.0 as divisor, just personal taste.

In any case, the key is to only modify `gl_FragColor.rgb` and leave alone the 'gl_FragColor.a` (the alpha channel).

I was working on a quick and dirty scanline effect too and arrived to this question after searching for `gl_FragCoord.y` and `mod`. The `floor(gl_fragCoord.y)` in your question solved my problem.